# How to get bounds for the remainder of the Binomial Series?

Tags: real-analysis

If $|x|<1$ it is know that $$(1+x)^\alpha=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{\alpha}{n}x^n$$ i know how to prove this, (by showing that $\lim_{n\to\infty}R_{n,0}(x)=0$). But my question here is the following: it is posible to give an upper bound for the 
remainder (Taylor polinomial) in the form, $$|R_n(x)|\leq A^n$$ where $A$ is a constant? If the answer is yes, how can i find $A$? I specifically want to know how to approximate an expression (as example $\sqrt{1.05}=(1+0.5)^{1/2}$) using the binomial series with the number of digits of accuracy desired. I am working in this problem but without success.

PD: This is not a homework!
Any help are welcome, thanks!

Comment: What is the set from which $\alpha$ is chosen?  I.e., is the series conveniently finite ($\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$) or not?

Comment: In your example, you have $|x|=1$, not $|x|<1$...

Comment: $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Its true thanks. Note the change.

Comment: For example if am trying to estimate $\sqrt[5]{35}$ with 6 decimal place of precision. How can i do it? My approach is to write $\sqrt[5]{35}=2(1+3/32)^{1/5}$ and use the binomial theorem to expand $(1+3/32)^{1/5}$ but i don't know how to get a bound like $|R_n(x)|\leq A^n$ for estimate this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=k}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{n} x^n = x^k \binom{\alpha}{k} {}_2F_1(1,k-\alpha; 1+k;-x) = x^k \binom{\alpha}{k}\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \frac{(1)_\ell(k-\alpha)_\ell}{(k+1)_\ell} \frac{(-x)^{\ell}}{\ell!}$$ where the $(\cdot)_\ell$ are Pochhammer symbols (ascending factorials stopping at $\ell$ terms).  I don't see a useful constant bound on $\sqrt[k]{{}_2F_1(1,k-\alpha; 1+k;-x)}$.  For instance, for $\alpha = 1/2$, the singular behaviour near $x=-1$ is unavoidable.  And this sort of singularity is generally unavoidable because $\alpha$ could be negative (leading to $\alpha$ order poles for $x$ near $-1$) or fractional (leading to vertical derivatives for $x$ near $-1$).

If you could restrict $x$ to nonnegatives, then this *might* be possible.  Numerical experiments suggest $1 \leq \sqrt[k]{{}_2F_1(1,k-\frac{1}{2}; 1+k;-x)} \leq 2$ for $x \in [0,1]$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 3):

In a case such as $(1+1)^\alpha$ with $\alpha$ a non-integer, the terms do not go to zero exponentially (because this is at the radius of convergence), so neither do the remainders.  In particular for $\alpha = 1/2$ the $n$'th term is (according to Maple) asymptotic to $(-1)^{n+1}/(2 \sqrt{\pi} n^{3/2})$. 
But you don't need precise bounds, because (for $x > 0$) the signs of the terms are
alternating: as long as the terms are decreasing in magnitude and go to $0$ 
the sum is between any two successive terms.  So just keep taking more terms until
you get a term whose absolute value is less than your desired $\epsilon$.